Vintage Bathroom Tile Patch
I need to patch these missing vintage tiles as well as remove the tile to the right and the left of each. Substrate is very hard and tile chips easily. What tools and processes are needed to do this? https://imgur.com/a/DDLOcP1

Do you have spare tiles?

What are you patching the tile with?  That can determine what may be the best course of action.
